# Selenium href for loop not completing

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I've been stuck with this problem for a couple of weeks now, and have looked everywhere to try and solve it. I'm trying to scrap some information for the's sun website sports page. I can get the title of the boxes and an even the little description underneath it, but when I try and get the `href` the loop stops part way through and throws up an

```
error(selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//a"}).
```

This is the code that I have been running. I initally thought it was a element finding issue until I added the print(link) as I was only getting back the first link or just the error. I have tried chaging the way it is found eg by xpath, css or tag and so on but no luck either

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

website = 'https://www.thesun.co.uk/sport/football/'
path = 'D:\\Programming\\Automate with Python\\Automating\\chromedriver_win32'
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('detach', True)

service = Service(executable_path=path)
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
browser.get(website)

containers = browser.find_elements(by="xpath", value='//div[@class="teaser__copy-container"]')

titles = []
sub_titles = []
links = []

for container in containers:
    title = container.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span').get_attribute("textContent")
    sub_title = container.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'h3').get_attribute("textContent")
    link = container.find_element(By.XPATH, './/a').get_attribute("href")
    titles.append(title)
    sub_titles.append(sub_title)
    links.append(link)
    print(link)

df_headlines = pd.DataFrame({'title': titles, 'sub-title': sub_titles, 'links': links})
df_headlines.to_csv('headline.csv')
```

could it be a broken link on the website? Any help would be appreciated as this has been a bit of a challenge and I would like to solve it, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It fails because one of the containers don't have "a" element. You can check on dev tools console

```
$x("//div[@class='teaser__copy-container']")
```

returns 68 elements,

`$x("//div[@class='teaser__copy-container']//a")`

returns 67.

To know what element is `$x("//div[@class='teaser__copy-container'` and not(`.//a)]`)

As I explained, change this line. This will force container have "a" element inside. Or try-except find_elements and set default value empty link

```
containers = browser.find_elements(by="xpath", value='//div[@class="teaser__copy-container" and .//a]')
```

Comment: Thank you, was fantastic to finally see it work.